# Is there a product for Web to Case or Email to Case that can capture device information like browser or operating system?

Tags: email2case, web-to-case

Is there a product for Web to Case or Email to Case that can capture device information like browser or operating system?

I have been searching Salesforce, Google, this site, and the most relevant result I've found is the Meta Info Question for Qualtrics XM product: https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/editing-questions/question-types-guide/advanced/meta-info-question/

Hoping for a product more limited in scope than purchasing the whole XM product.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You really only need [window.navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator), which is built in to the browser, to get detailed information, which you can then place directly into your form's input fields for submission.

Comment: why would you need this for email-2-case?  there's not always a browser involved. Any information about the source of the email would be within the message's headers